# Convert VB6 Scripting.Dictionary to .NET Generic Dictionary

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

Currently im working on wrapping and converting some old VB6 code to .NET and i need to be able to use the scripting.dictionary returned by huge old price of VB6 code.

I want to convert this to the .NET generic Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to write an extension method for scripting.dictionary to convert to a .net Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)

**VB.NET**

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ToDictionary(Of T, T2)(dic As Scripting.Dictionary) As Dictionary(Of T, T2)
    Return dic.Cast(Of Object)().ToDictionary(Function(i) CType(i, T), Function(i) CType(dic.Item(i), T2))
End Function
```

**C#.NET**

```
[Extension()]
public static Dictionary<T, T2> ToDictionary<T, T2>(Scripting.Dictionary dic)
{
    return dic.Cast<object>().ToDictionary(i => (T)i, i => (T2)dic.Item(i));
}
```

and then simply use

```
horribleDictionary.toDictionary<int,string>()
```