# Scripting.Dictionary with Option Script disallows late binding

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I have migrated VB6 code to Vb.Net and turned `Option strict On`.

Now, `.Keys(intIndex)` is throwing the exception `Option Strict On disallows late binding`. Below is the code:

```
Public Function PopulateList(ByRef dicListValues As Scripting.Dictionary)
    Dim strKey As String
    With dicListValues
        For intIndex = 0 To .Count - 1
            strKey = .Keys(intIndex)
        Next
    End With
```

Comment: .Keys(intIndex).ToString() perhaps. I don't see late binding in your posted code

Comment: in  code its throwing error because option strict is on. FYR,  Scripting.IDictionary.Keys() As Object

Comment: Sorry still not clicking with me. Can you update your code with the declaration of the variable?

Comment: updated the question with declaration. only those are the declaration. Scripting.Dictionary will be instantiated using Interop.Scripting.dll. hope this helps.

Comment: If you migrated from vb6 to vb.net, why continue to use Scripting.Dictionary? You can even make an extension to convert to the .NET Dictionary https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136733/convert-vb6-scripting-dictionary-to-net-generic-dictionary

Comment: Also, we don't know what is in the dictionary because Scripting.Dictionary wasn't generic. So you would need to tell us what the dictionary has inside. I guess the key is a string from context. Then all you need to do is what @UnhandledExcepSean suggested in his first comment.

Comment: Thats a somewhat silly use of a With/End With block.  It actually takes more lines and more typing to use versus `dicListValues.Keys(intIndex)`  It only ever had any alleged value in VB6, no more need for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer,  if you want to use Scripting.Dictionary to work when option strict option on.

```
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary '= New Scripting.DictionaryClass()
    Dim str As String
    dict.Add("1", 10)
    dict.Add(2, "20")
    dict.Add(Math.PI, "Test")

    dict.Add(New Text.StringBuilder(), "builder")
    For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
        str = CType(DirectCast(dict.Keys, Object())(i), String)
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's why you don't want to use Scripting.Dictionary

```
Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary = New Scripting.DictionaryClass()
dict.Add("1", 1)
dict.Add(2, "2")
dict.Add(Math.PI, "a")
dict.Add(New Text.StringBuilder(), "builder")
For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", dict.Keys(i), dict(dict.Keys(i)))
Next
```

You can see that `dict.Keys(i)` and `dict(dict.Keys(i))` (the key and value of the dictionary) can be any type which is an Object (every type).

Ok, so assume you have all strings.

```
Dim strKey As String
With dicListValues
    For intIndex = 0 To .Count - 1
        strKey = .Keys(intIndex).ToString()
    Next
End With
```

(You can control it by only adding strings, but this is not apparent unless you comment well).

The better solution would be to replace your Scripting.Dictionary with a [Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) in your entire project. You can convert your Scripting.Dictionary to them with the link I commented before [Convert VB6 Scripting.Dictionary to .NET Generic Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136733/convert-vb6-scripting-dictionary-to-net-generic-dictionary)